# Trim string parameters using $PSBoundParameters

Tags: string, powershell, trim

I have a function which has a lot of parameters and I'd like to trim any string parameters passed in. I put together a loop of $PSBoundParameters and it will change the variable, but not keep the change when the individual variable is called later on.

```
function TrimStringParameters
{   [CmdletBinding()]
    param( [string] $var )
    foreach ($key in $($PSBoundParameters.keys)) {
        if ($($PSBoundParameters[$key]).GetType().Name -eq "String") {
            write-verbose "before '$($PSBoundParameters[$key])'"
            $PSBoundParameters[$key] = $($PSBoundParameters[$key].trim())
            write-verbose "After '$($PSBoundParameters[$key])'"
            Set-Variable -Name $($PSBoundParameters[$key]) -Value $($PSBoundParameters[$key].trim())
            write-verbose "After After '$($PSBoundParameters[$key])'"
        }
    }
    Write-verbose "`$var = '$var'"
}
```

Is there a way to do this without specifying each variable in turn?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out!

the line:

```
$PSBoundParameters[$key] = $($PSBoundParameters[$key].trim())
```

doesn't seem to do anything long term, but the Set-Variable line does

```
Set-Variable -Name $($PSBoundParameters[$key]) -Value $($PSBoundParameters[$key].trim())
```

The problem was the Set-Variable line should have used the $key variable for the Name parameter!

```
Set-Variable -Name $key -Value $($PSBoundParameters[$key].trim())
```

It is still odd to me that you need the Set-Variable command but I guess it needs to be around for some reason!

Comment: I was just about to tell you to do that. Good work. It would appear that `$PSBoundParameters` is a copy of the parameters and not directly linked to them ... possibly